# When I change assignee for my approval rule 'GxP Enabled Approval', I get below error when I try to hit the approval rule

Tags: apex, cpq, approval-step

When I change assignee for my approval rule 'GxP Enabled Approval', I get below error when I try to hit the approval rule.

Error:
{faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'Apttus_Approval.ApprovalSystemException: Error creating approval requests: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Opportunity_AEs_Manager__c (Apttus_Approval)', }

I have changed the assignee for other approval rules as well and they are working fine. Could someone please help?